# Do we like hats?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is doing an event this year in which... well, let me just use Aarthi's words:

> ## Winter Bash 2012
>
> Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called Hat Dash, where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".
>
> For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor. [...]
>
> This year, we're expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate, and redesigning the hat selection to be more appropriate to the entire network (no severed Wampa heads). Some of it is holiday-themed, some of it is a bit silly, and all of it is (hopefully) fun!
>
> ## Some Nitty-Gritty
>
> This event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available, just as we had on Gaming last year.
>
> The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

Here's a screenshot from last year's Hat Dash on Gaming SE:

[image: screenshot]

As the message says, this can be disabled for each individual site and for each individual user. So if this is something you individually would not be interested in, you can just opt out, but if it's something the whole community would be uninterested in, we can just decide as a site not to participate. What do people think?

Comment: Hahaha, this could be fun :-D

Comment: Nobody's objected, so I'm going to indicate our agreement to participate in the promotion.

Answer (score 4):

Do we choose what takes get reputation, or is it just an extension of the general upvote system? *If* it's combined with some improvement of the sites questions, I'm for it. Some threads could get a clear up, or some closure.

(What should be our hats though? I know Hilbert was wearing a prominent hat. Who else? Well there is of course [Feynamn wearing a hat](http://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/2012/2/25/42e726a5-d173-446e-96d8-d337612c0508.png).)

Comment: Some physicists obviously like [cowboy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Polchinski) hats ... :-D

Comment: The hats don't get you extra rep. They're like the badges--you can earn them and they're uniform across all sites (you earn them the same way). We _may_ be able to get custom hats, but don't count on it..

Comment: Effectively, it's an extension of *normal site usage*, as action such as editing, flagging, voting, answering, etc. will all earn you hats. As @Manishearth pointed out above: hats are badges you can *wear*. They're (to use a term from gaming) equippable. It's a fun, two-week event that is meant to provide a certain amount of lightheartedness to the network at large. Unfortunately, currently, there aren't plans for site-specific hats. Those would depend on what our one-man design team has the bandwidth for. I hope you understand.